# Equation labels on rows of an array?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath, labels, arrays

I'm trying to typeset some sets of linear equations, and I'd like the variables to be vertically aligned, sort of like this:

```
   x     -  z =  4                     (12)
 -3x - y + 2z = -6                     (13)
  2x +7y -12z = 57                     (14)
```

I can align variables in an `array` environment, and I can number equations with the `align` environment (and its variations), but can I do both together?

Comment: Something similar to `alignat` environment from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `alignat`, with some hints for getting correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
  x &    &    &-{} &   z &={} &  4 \\
-3x &-{} &  y &+{} &  2z &={} & -6 \\
 2x &+{} & 7y &-{} & 12z &={} & 57
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `alignat` builds pairs of “right-left” aligned columns, with no space intervening between these pairs.

So we need four such pairs, for each variable and operation/relation. The second column of each pair implicitly starts with `{}`, but we need another `{}` after the operation/relation symbol, in order to get the correct spacing.

[image]

If you want a brace at the left, you can use `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{alignat=4}
  x &    &    &-{} &   z &={} &  4 \\
-3x &-{} &  y &+{} &  2z &={} & -6 \\
 2x &+{} & 7y &-{} & 12z &={} & 57
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you require the `alignat` feature from `amsmath`. An example is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\ms{{\,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
  x&    &   -z &=  4&\\
-3x&  -y& + 2z &= -6&\\
 2x& +7y& -12z &= 57&
\end{alignat}  
or
\begin{alignat}{7}
  x&   &   & \ms- \ms&   z &\ms=\ms&  4&\\
-3x&  \ms-\ms&  y& \ms+ \ms&  2z &\ms=\ms& -6&\\
 2x&  \ms+\ms& 7y& \ms- \ms& 12z &\ms=\ms& 57&
\end{alignat}  

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
I have now added thin spaces around math align operators using a command `\ms`. Thanks to @barbarabeeton and @Bernard.

Comment: Many thanks indeed!- alignat does do the job, especially in the second configuration.  I just need to work out the best way of increasing the column separation, and I'll be good to go.

Comment: @Jagath: there is a bad spacing around `=` in eq. (6). You should use `&={}&` for this equation.

Comment: @Bernard: I will update the answer soon.

Comment: the spacing is also bad in several places in equation (5),  empty groups `{}` around all the signs of relation and operation (except the initial minus) should fix that.